# Convert 7.346000E-001 or 7.3460000E+000 to Double

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, double, type-conversion, exponential

I'm trying to convert a string value to Double but I sill get error saying that the format is incorrect.

My Strings are represented like this : `7.346000E-001`, `7.3460000E+000`

Is there another way to convert them or I need to truncate the string into two parts and do the calculation by myself to get the real value ?

Comment: How are you doing the conversion? `Convert.ToDouble("7.3460000E-001")` works for me, are you sure you're not using culture-specific parsing?

Comment: you should be able to convert in one step, what code did you use ?

Comment: I'm using Double.Parse("7.346000E-001")

Comment: @Wassim What's the value of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` then?

Comment: Convert.ToDouble("7.3460000E-001",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) would help if you are on a culture using , as a decimal separator

Comment: @millimoose CultureInfo.CurrentCulture returns {fr-FR}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` with `double.parse`

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR"); // just to simulate french culture
double d = double.Parse("7.3460000E-001",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.Write(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

French culture (I assumed it from your profile) uses comma instead of the dot as the decimal separator.

Solution described here: [C# float.tryparse for French Culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722831/c-sharp-float-tryparse-for-french-culture)