# Parsing floats with Single.TryParse fails

Tags: c#, floating-point, tryparse

There is an article on Single.TryParse over at MSDN with this example code:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26sxas5t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

```
// Parse a floating-point value with a thousands separator.
value = "1,643.57";
if (Single.TryParse(value, out number))
    Console.WriteLine(number);
else
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{0}'.", value);
```

Problem is in the article the TryParse returns `true` and the string is converted, but when I try it, it's `false`. How do I fix this?

---

**UPD:** To simplify parsing, these two lines can be used:

```
NumberStyles style = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any;
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

This setting allows for negative floats and strings with leading and trailing space characters to be parsed.

Comment: Is your system culture one that uses `,` as a thousands separator and `.` as a decimal separator?  In Germany for example, that is not the case.

Comment: Your problem is probably the culture. Your number can only be parsed if the culture uses `.` as decimal seperator. So you should use an overload that takes a culture, and specify `InvariantCulture`.

Comment: Oh, so it's the separator. For a moment there I thought some kind of bad karma is involved.

Comment: Clearly the problem is you're not in America.  Time to move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to set culture like this

```
using System.Globalization;

string value = "1345,978";
NumberStyles style = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
CultureInfo culture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
if (Single.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", value);
```

from msdn  : [Single.TryParse Method (String, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider, Single%)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xh24xh4.aspx)

or

```
float usedAmount;
// try parsing with "fr-FR" first
bool success = float.TryParse(inputUsedAmount.Value,
                              NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                              CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"),
                              out usedAmount);

if (!success)
{
    // parsing with "fr-FR" failed so try parsing with InvariantCulture
    success = float.TryParse(inputUsedAmount.Value,
                             NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands,
                             CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                             out usedAmount);
}

if (!success)
{
    // parsing failed with both "fr-FR" and InvariantCulture
}
```

Answered over here : [C# float.tryparse for French Culture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722831/c-sharp-float-tryparse-for-french-culture)

Comment: NumberStyles and CultureInfo are not recognized keywords. `Using` what can I work with them?

Comment: you need to add using System.Globalization;

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with your culture about :  **,** character

You can use `CultureInvariant` in your string